# Using Application.Run in Class Library

Tags: c#

I have read in these forums where invoking Application.Run more than once is bad because it creates more than one message pump which throws an exception. My question is... Is it okay or bad practice if a windows application, uses a class library, which contains windows form(s) and Application.Run is invoked from within the class library in order to show a form. A class method would wrap over the call or invocation of Application.Run(new frmMyForm) in order to show it.

Something to keep in mind about the application I have encountered in this scenario:
The dlls extend the application functionality and the form(s) as classes within the DLL do not return data or state back to the main application but rather do independent tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with that. It's really up to you how you want to package the code that makes that call. Wrapping it in a class library is not conceptually different from just wrapping it in a simple method called from your main method.